# G Suite Developer Sheets Quickstart tutorial: TypeError in "check student attendance"

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-script-addon

Following the steps in the G Suite Developer Sheets Add-on Samples tutorial
[Quickstart: Check Student Attendance In Google Meet Courses](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/editors/sheets/quickstart/attendance)

I completed all 10 steps in **Set up**, but on step 2 in **Try it out** the ***Options > Import Last 5 Courses*** causes a error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

It fails in both Chromium and Microsoft Edge browsers.  From looking at the script, it seems like Classroom.Courses.list() is returning null.

Unable to import the data, I can't run rest of the tutorial.

Comment: Which line of the script is giving this type error? `importCourses` calls `insertCourse` which also uses `.length`.

Answer (score 0):

So based on my experience building stuff with google apps script, (see tutoringbyroger.com), I suspect that you **might** be encountering a weird permissions issue. If it didn't ask for permissions to run the script, try the following:

1. In the script editor select the importCourses() function from the dropdown.
2. Click the debug icon.

That should prompt for any necessary permissions and run the function. It might fail, but at least that will get the permissions out of the way.

If you have already done that, or it already asked for permissions then... ??? I am just as stumped as you. Maybe tell Google or search their support page?

Other things to double-check before reporting it as a bug:

1. Make sure you have done step 6 in the "Set up" section.
2. Make sure you have admin permissions.

Other than that, it should work. If it doesn't I don't know what to tell you.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion IMO, You're not crossing the line, but I think  you don't have to advertise your website on every answer. Also see https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/182212